# Application.Caller for ActiveX Labels

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 ActiveX labels with name that begins with "Label_". ActiveX A label is Label_AAA, and B label is Label_BBB and so on.

I would like to loop through all OleObjects where label.name contains "Label", check which label was last clicked, and return the label.name.

Any idea how I could use Application.Caller with ActiveX Labels to find the last clicked label?

```
Dim InfoSheet As Worksheet
Set InfoSheet = Sheet3

Dim label As OLEObject

For Each label In InfoSheet.OLEObjects
    If InStr(1, label.name, "Label") Then

    'check which is the last clicked label and return label.name 

    End If
Next label
```

Comment: Is there code attached to these labels being clicked?

Comment: Hi, no there's no code at the moment attached to each label.

Comment: Any help is appreciated. I just need to be able to know the last clicked activex label..